# bonsai R package installation problem in windows

Tags: r, cran, lightgbm, tidymodels, r-parsnip

I intent to run a lightgbm model in R using tidymodels.
I installed bonsai in mac like usual but I'm finding trouble doing it on my windows machine. It also works well in Posit Cloud.
I tried the install.packages and the pak:: method like instructed in the repo https://github.com/tidymodels/bonsai

Here is what I have tried and the erros I'm getting:

```
 install.packages("bonsai")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/dani1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/bonsai_0.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 158788 bytes (155 KB)
downloaded 155 KB

package ‘bonsai’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\dani1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOmjyZF\downloaded_packages
> library(bonsai)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bonsai’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'bonsai', details:
  call: is_discordant_info(model, mode, eng, new_fit)
  error: The combination of engine 'lightgbm' and mode 'regression'  already has fit data for model 'boost_tree' and the new information being registered is different.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘bonsai’ was built under R version 4.2.3 
> **pak::pak("tidymodels/bonsai")**
                                                                           
→ Will update 1 package.
→ Will download 1 package with unknown size.
+ bonsai 0.2.1 → 0.2.1.9000 [bld][cmp][dl] (GitHub: aab79d5)
? Do you want to continue (Y/n) Y
ℹ Getting 1 pkg with unknown size
✔ Cached copy of bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (source) is the latest build
✔ No downloads needed, all packages are cached           
ℹ Packaging bonsai 0.2.1.9000
✔ Packaged bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (1.1s)                               
ℹ Building bonsai 0.2.1.9000                                      
✔ Built bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (5.4s)                                  
✔ Installed bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (github::tidymodels/bonsai@aab79d5) (127ms)
✔ 1 pkg + 43 deps: kept 27, upd 1 [19.3s]                           
> library(bonsai)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bonsai’ in get(method, envir = envir):
 lazy-load database 'C:/Users/dani1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/bonsai/R/bonsai.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(method, envir = envir) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
> doParallel::registerDoParallel()
> light_grid <- tune_grid(
+   light_wf,
+   resamples = cv_folds,
+   grid = 10,
+   control = control_grid(save_pred = T)
+ )
i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
Error in `check_installs()`:
! Some package installs are required: 
• 'bonsai', 'bonsai'
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: In get(method, envir = envir) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
2: In get(method, envir = envir) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
>
```

Does anyone has a workaround this?

Edit: Repeat and give the results of sessionInfo()

```
> # Remove Package
> remove.packages("bonsai")
Removing package from ‘C:/Users/dani1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> # Reinstall CRAN
> install.packages("bonsai")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/dani1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/bonsai_0.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 158788 bytes (155 KB)
downloaded 155 KB

package ‘bonsai’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\dani1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOmjyZF\downloaded_packages
> #load
> library(bonsai)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bonsai’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'bonsai', details:
  call: is_discordant_info(model, mode, eng, new_fit)
  error: The combination of engine 'lightgbm' and mode 'regression'  already has fit data for model 'boost_tree' and the new information being registered is different.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘bonsai’ was built under R version 4.2.3 
> # pak
> pak::pak("tidymodels/bonsai")
                                                                      
→ Will update 1 package.
→ Will download 1 package with unknown size.
+ bonsai 0.2.1 → 0.2.1.9000 [bld][cmp][dl] (GitHub: aab79d5)
? Do you want to continue (Y/n) Y
ℹ Getting 1 pkg with unknown size
✔ Cached copy of bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (source) is the latest build
✔ No downloads needed, all packages are cached                      
ℹ Packaging bonsai 0.2.1.9000
✔ Packaged bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (1.2s)                               
ℹ Building bonsai 0.2.1.9000                                      
✔ Built bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (7.7s)                                  
✔ Installed bonsai 0.2.1.9000 (github::tidymodels/bonsai@aab79d5) (253ms)
✔ 1 pkg + 43 deps: kept 27, upd 1 [19.3s]                           
> #load
> library(bonsai)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bonsai’ in get(method, envir = envir):
 lazy-load database 'C:/Users/dani1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/bonsai/R/bonsai.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(method, envir = envir) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
> # session
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] themis_1.0.0       forcats_0.5.1      stringr_1.5.0     
 [4] readr_2.1.2        tidyverse_1.3.1    yardstick_1.0.0   
 [7] workflowsets_1.0.0 workflows_1.0.0    tune_1.0.0        
[10] tidyr_1.3.0        tibble_3.1.8       rsample_1.0.0     
[13] recipes_1.0.1      purrr_1.0.1        parsnip_1.0.4     
[16] modeldata_1.0.0    infer_1.0.2        ggplot2_3.3.6     
[19] dplyr_1.1.0        dials_1.0.0        scales_1.2.0      
[22] broom_1.0.0        tidymodels_1.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_2.0-3   ellipsis_0.3.2     class_7.3-20      
 [4] fs_1.5.2           rstudioapi_0.14    listenv_0.8.0     
 [7] furrr_0.3.1        remotes_2.4.2      bit64_4.0.5       
[10] prodlim_2019.11.13 fansi_1.0.4        lubridate_1.8.0   
[13] xml2_1.3.3         codetools_0.2-18   splines_4.2.0     
[16] doParallel_1.0.17  jsonlite_1.8.4     dbplyr_2.2.0      
[19] compiler_4.2.0     httr_1.4.4         backports_1.4.1   
[22] assertthat_0.2.1   Matrix_1.5-1       cli_3.6.0         
[25] tools_4.2.0        gtable_0.3.0       glue_1.6.2        
[28] Rcpp_1.0.10        cellranger_1.1.0   DiceDesign_1.9    
[31] vctrs_0.5.2        tree_1.0-43        iterators_1.0.14  
[34] timeDate_3043.102  gower_1.0.0        globals_0.16.2    
[37] rvest_1.0.3        lifecycle_1.0.3    pak_0.4.0         
[40] future_1.26.1      MASS_7.3-56        ipred_0.9-13      
[43] vroom_1.5.7        hms_1.1.1          parallel_4.2.0    
[46] lightgbm_3.3.5     rpart_4.1.16       stringi_1.7.12    
[49] foreach_1.5.2      lhs_1.1.5          hardhat_1.2.0     
[52] lava_1.6.10        rlang_1.0.6        pkgconfig_2.0.3   
[55] lattice_0.20-45    bit_4.0.4          tidyselect_1.2.0  
[58] parallelly_1.32.0  magrittr_2.0.3     R6_2.5.1          
[61] generics_0.1.3     DBI_1.1.3          pillar_1.8.1      
[64] haven_2.5.0        withr_2.5.0        survival_3.3-1    
[67] nnet_7.3-17        future.apply_1.9.0 ROSE_0.0-4        
[70] modelr_0.1.8       crayon_1.5.1       utf8_1.2.3        
[73] tzdb_0.3.0         grid_4.2.0         readxl_1.4.1      
[76] data.table_1.14.2  reprex_2.0.1       digest_0.6.29     
[79] GPfit_1.0-8        munsell_0.5.0
```

Comment: Can you repeat and give the results of `sessionInfo()` afterwards?

Comment: Updated and now it works fine! Should've thought about that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you start off by restarting your R session before calling `library(bonsai)`? I would anticipate this is the cause of the `is_discordant_info()` error.

If that doesn't do the trick, you're seeing the warning:

> RTools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding.

RTools is a set of packages needed on Windows to build R packages from source. Here are some [instructions for installing RTools](https://ohdsi.github.io/Hades/rSetup.html#Installing_RTools)—work through those, restart R, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Updated R version, R studio, and restarted session. Working perfectly now, thank you so much @Simon Couch.